# Best sphinx workflow for large project with long compile time

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm working in a large sphinx project with long compile time.
I want to find a way to compile my file(s) of interest without dealing with the entire project.

One way to reduce this is to create an `index_small.rst` and change the makefile to use that rst instead of the standard index.rst.

One problem with this is that I get warnings for all the rst files I haven't included in the toc tree.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`exclude_patterns` and `:orphan:`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html) directives on your `index_small.rst`:

> Use [`exclude_patterns`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-exclude_patterns) to explicitly exclude documents or directories from building completely. Use [the “orphan”](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/misc.html#metadata) metadata to let a document be built, but notify Sphinx that it is not reachable via a toctree.